# Tetris Deleting Rows Issue

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to create a Tetris game in XNA to better learn to make a better game in the future.  The only problem I am having is the 'deleting rows' functionality of the game.  I have a integer matrix to hold all the rows count of the blocks in them.  Whenever I create a new block, I increment the count by one in the specified row.  Then, I check to see if any of the values in the matrix has met or exceeded 10.  Then if it has, I delete all the blocks in said row.  The problem I am having is that it's not reliable, and it doesn't keep track of the count as well as it should for some reason, and sometimes- it won't delete all the blocks in the row.  If you need to see any other classes, let me know.  Thanks, help is appreciated.

```
public class Main : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    //Texture for the block
    public static Texture2D block;
    //Font 
    public static SpriteFont font1;
    //Which shape we're dealing with(Moving)
    public static int shapeIndex;
    //The next shape, the one we can see previewed
    public static Shape nextShape;
    //The first shape we use
    public static Shape s2;
    //All the shapes
    public static List<Shape> shapes = new List<Shape>();
    //All the blocks that have stopped moving (The shapes are converted to blocks when they stop moving to make for easier deletion)
    public static List<Block> blocks = new List<Block>();
    //The count of blocks in each row
    public static int[] rowCount = new int[20];

    public Main()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 500;
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        this.IsMouseVisible = true;
        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        block = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites//TetrisBlock");
        font1 = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts//GameFont");
        //Creating a random shape
        switch (new Random().Next(1, 3))
        { 
            case 1:
                nextShape = new Shape(Shape.Shapes.tShape, new Vector2(550, 0), false);
                break;
            case 2:
                nextShape = new Shape(Shape.Shapes.lineShape, new Vector2(550, 0), false);
                break;
        }
        //The current shape we're dealing with
        shapeIndex = 0;
        //Creating the first shape
        s2 = new Shape(Shape.Shapes.lineShape, new Vector2(), true);
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //If the blocks that are still are rainbow, have them cycle through their colors
        foreach (Block b in nextShape.Blocks)
        {
            if (b.RainbowBlock)
                b.changeColor(gameTime);
        }
        //Update all the shapes
        for (int i = 0; i < shapes.Count; i++)
        {
            shapes[i].Update(gameTime);
        }
        //If the shape has hit another shape and stopped moving
        if (!shapes[shapeIndex].MoveDown)
        {
            //For every block that was in the shape, add it to the block list and increase that row's count by one
            foreach (Block b in shapes[shapeIndex].Blocks)
            {
                blocks.Add(b);
                rowCount[b.Row]++;
            }
            //Remove that shape
            shapes.RemoveAt(shapeIndex);
            //The current shape we need to move
            Shape s3 = nextShape;
            s3.Position = new Vector2();
            s3.Imaginary = false;
            shapes.Add(s3);
            //Creating a new random shape for the next shape
            switch (new Random().Next(1, 4))
            {
                case 1:
                    nextShape = new Shape(Shape.Shapes.tShape, new Vector2(550, 0), false);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    nextShape = new Shape(Shape.Shapes.lineShape, new Vector2(550, 0), false);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    nextShape = new Shape(Shape.Shapes.lShape, new Vector2(550, 0), false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        //Testing whether or not rows have reached their maximum capacity
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount.Length; i++)
        {
            //If a row has reached its capacity
            if (rowCount[i] >= 10)
            {
                //Remove that row
                removeRow(i);
                //Move all blocks that are above that row down one
                foreach (Block b in blocks)
                {
                    if (b.Row < i)
                    {
                        //Subtract the old rowcount by one
                        rowCount[b.Row]--;
                        b.Row++;
                        //Add one to the rowcount(If I remove this, it seems to work a little better but it still has issues)
                        rowCount[b.Row]++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Update all the blocks that are still
        foreach (Block b in blocks)
            b.Update(gameTime);
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    //Remove the row specified in the parameters
    public void removeRow(int row)
    {
        //For every block
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.Count; i++)
        {
            //See if it's in the row the user wants to remove
            if (blocks[i].Row.Equals(row))
            {
                //If it is, remove it and decrement that row's rowcount
                blocks.RemoveAt(i);
                rowCount[row]--;
                //Here was the problem, I wasn't decrementing i to check the next block
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        //Draws every shape in the game
        foreach (Shape s in shapes)
            s.Draw(spriteBatch);
        //Draws all the blocks at the bottom that have stopped moving
        foreach (Block b in blocks)
            b.Draw(spriteBatch);
        //Info for me
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, "Next Block:", new Vector2(430, 0), Color.Black);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font1, rowCount[19].ToString() + " " + blocks.Count + " Blocks", new Vector2(300, 0), Color.Black);
        //For the next shape, draw every block so we know what it looks like
        foreach (Block b in nextShape.Blocks)
            b.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

[EDIT]
The parts moving down works just fine, it's just deleting rows that troublesome.  I also tried to comment as best I could, if you have any questions, just ask.  Thanks again.

Comment: It is not easy helping you. The code is not commented and its structure, although seems fine at a first sight, is not too good. You cannot expect us to debug/execute, understand it and find the problems. You should include lots of comments or explain clearly what the relevant parts do (e.g., where is called removeRow, all the variables involve, etc.), the exact problems you find, what works fine, etc.

Comment: I tried to comment as best I could, would anything else help?

Comment: Much, much better. This code is certainly clear. Unfortunately I am leaving already (and it is pretty late here). Tomorrow I will come back and try to help you if the problem is still not solved.

Comment: You haven't said anything I have got a -1. Although I have been lately the target of a psycho downvoting systematically my answers, so no idea what might be the reason... In any case, I guess that I have been pretty patient and your silence does not seem the kind or reward I would expect when someone intends to help so... I will better delete the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did get a chance to view your answer but I have so swamped with other things, I have not had the chance to reply.  I see that it's not the best coding, but my intent was to get and answer as to why this particular code wasn't working, as I couldn't figure it out on my own.  I know bugfixing is a major part of programming, so I was hoping to get a little insight into that.  I was planning on rewriting this at some point anyway, but I wanted to learn this program's flaw first.  Sorry if I seemed ungrateful for your answer.

Comment: Well... It seems that we see things very differently: if I ask for help and someone helps me (by letting very clear that he will come back to me the next day) I would consider pretty ungrateful and unpolite delaying the answer over 1 week. You didn't even read my answer? What a shame! Summary: your code doesn't have a specific bug, but represents a completely bad approach to the problem (I am saying this from a general-algorithm-building point of view, not even from a gaming point of view). You have to redo it; my answer only included some guidelines to do that.

Comment: Hmm...  It was a specific bug, when I was iterating through the blocks and deleting them, I didn't decrement my iteration variable- meaning all the blocks wouldn't get checked.

Comment: No, it wasn't a specific bug. Your whole approach is wrong. Making something wrong to (eventually) work is not fixing it.

Comment: It was a solution to the specific problem I was having, ergo I fixed that specific bug.  It does work now, and just because you don't see it as a good approach doesn't mean it's wrong.  I'm no programming expert, but my approach is just as valid as any other.

Comment: If I would be you, after saying "I'm no programming expert", I wouldn't ever say "my approach is just as valid as any other" (I mean... not without given reasons, understanding what the other person proposes, etc.). Anyway... if someone reads this in the future, at least, would not waste his/her time unnecessarily: second, a-bit-more-expert opinion (don't try this) + your solution is not immediately applicable (apparently you care about helping future readers as much as about being respectful to people intending to help you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was iterating through the blocks that I was checking, if I deleted it, I didn't decrement the iteration variable to check the next block- so all the blocks weren't being checked.

Comment: You shouldn't write this as a solution (or, at least, should have posted the whole corrected code (what you defined as a block how are you using it in your algorithm is not even clear); what, eventually, someone might find helpful): your whole algorithm is, at least, unclear/not-well-structured. The ideal solution is redoing it. In any case, as explained, I didn't like your attitude too much, so... why insisting? Completely up to you.